# How does 'binding' in JSF work?

Tags: java, jsf, binding, jakarta-ee, custom-component

I've created custom component which shows chart.

Now I need to make binding support for this component i.e. generated chart-image should be available (as array of bytes) to backing bean via binding mechanism.

I'd like to know some general info about binding implementation techniques. Any links and examples are welcome as well.

Thanks in advance!

UPD: lets put it simple: on which phase value bindings are resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's on the `Update model values` phase.

But what does it matter - whenever you call an action method (`Invoke application`) the binding is already updated.

If you are asking how to do the binding - use a `private UIYourComponentName boundComponent` field on the bean.